Is it possible to use odd number of DIMM4 memory stick?
My computer is about 5 years old and everything is based on ASUS X399-A that uses DIMM4 3200 RAM. CPU is AMD Threadreaper 1950.
After series of BSoD's I decided to do a memory test using MemTest86+ and it turns out one of the 4 sticks installed in machine is broken. These are 16GB Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro.
I need an advice as I can't find any info whether RAM should be installed in pairs. The motherboard has pairs of banks A1/A2 B1/B2 --- CPU --- C1/C2 D1/D2 (here's the link to a X399-A manual.)

I suspect the order given is for the effective use of dual/triple/quad channel ram. While there may be advantages to the preferred order of ram installs, in the sort run, it might be fine to just pull the bad stick and seeing what happens

@Aibobot Yes, I tried exactly that and it's working. It's probably not optimal and not recommended. I orderrf extra pair of sticks, so for the time begin it's OK. Most of all the machine stopped BSoD

From the manual you provide go to page 1-5 and you will see the schema of memory population. You can have

1 slot - A1
2 slots - A1, C1
4 slots - A1, B1, C1, D1

etc..

I pulled out the damaged stick and that seemed  to help and made comp working so far. What's important is the computer is no longer turning to blue screen.

As noted by the other answer the Recommended memory configurations in the 1.1.4 System memory section of ASUS X399-A manual doesn't list 3 DIMMs as a scheme of memory population.
If look at the MSI MEG X399 CREATION manual which also supports a Ryzen Threadripper 1950X in a SocketTR4 CPU, then the MSI manual does show how to populate 3 DIMMs:



Therefore, suggest populate 3 DIMMs based upon the suggested slots given by name in the ASUS X399-A as shown above by the MSI MEG X399 CREATION manual. I.e. populate the DIMMs in slots D2, A2 and B2.
While the pictures of the DIMMs slots in the ASUS X399-A and MSI MEG X399 CREATION are in a different physical order, they use the same names. I.e. A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2.
This is on the assumption that the supported population order for DIMMs is based upon the X399-A chip set and Ryzen Threadripper 1950X, rather than specific to the type of motherboard.

Based on Asus manual the memory slots are totally different from your image. And for me will be not wise to use other schema than the manufacturer
